# Erro symfony após composer update

Tags: php, composer, symfony3

Quando eu executei os comandos

composer require symfony/filesystem
composer update , está ocorrendo o seguinte erro abaixo no meu projeto, em qualquer rota que eu acesse. Poderiam me ajudar ?Estou usando symfony 3.0 com banco de dados MySQL no servidor Apache.

`Uncaught ReflectionException: Class does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php:305 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php(305): ReflectionClass->__construct('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(771): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->addObjectResource('AppKernel') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(640): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(135): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Http in C:\xampp\htdocs\univrmanut_desenvolvimento\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 305`

Comment: Ta parecendo que está com algum problema de dependências do projeto, tente reinstalar as dependências

Comment: Consegui resolver! Removi a pasta Symfony da pasta vendor, executei o composer update novamente  e reiniciei o apache o servidor e o erro foi sanado. Obrigado!